# How to match data when ids have some signs or they have lower case or upper case

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to match two different files, but IDs have some signs or lower cases/uppercases.
Here is my data:

```html
df1<-read.table(text="id v1 v2 v3 
             xxx, 12 11 13
MMM w n m
                GgG Q n m
                bccde, w P m
                QMC NA T p
                
                ",h=T)
```

The second file is :

```html
df2<-read.table(text="id M4 N4 
             mmm 10 23
BcCde 11 11
                GGG, 12 5
                XXX 21 6
                
                ",h=T)
```

I want to get :

```html
df3<-read.table(text="id v1 v2 v3 M4 N4
            xxx, 12 11 13 21 6
MMM w n m 10 23
                GgG Q n m 12 5
                bccde, w P m 11 11
                QMC NA T p NA NA
                
                
                ",h=T)
```

I use merge, but does not work

```html
merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "id", all = TRUE)
```

Is it possible to sort my data out? Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `regex_left_join` from `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
regex_left_join(df1, mutate(df2, id = str_remove(id, ",")),
      by = "id", ignore_case = TRUE) %>%
      select(id = id.x, v1, v2, v3, M4, N4)
#       id   v1 v2 v3 M4 N4
#1   xxx,   12 11 13 21  6
#2    MMM    w  n  m 10 23
#3    GgG    Q  n  m 12  5
#4 bccde,    w  P  m 11 11
#5    QMC <NA>  T  p NA NA
```

---

Or with `select` `everything()`

```
regex_left_join(df1, mutate(df2, id = str_remove(id, ",")),
       by = "id", ignore_case = TRUE) %>% 
     select(everything(), id = id.x, -id.y) 
#      id   v1 v2 v3 M4 N4
#1   xxx,   12 11 13 21  6
#2    MMM    w  n  m 10 23
#3    GgG    Q  n  m 12  5
#4 bccde,    w  P  m 11 11
#5    QMC <NA>  T  p NA NA
```

Comment: Akrun@ thanks. However, it does not reflect my outcome. Could you check it

Comment: Thanks- select is an issue if we have many variables. Is it possible not to select ?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to correct ids for df2?

Comment: @user17  Where to correct.  If you check the 'df3', it is the same id

Answer (score 0):

You can convert all `ids` to lower case and then merge. Using `dplyr`,

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
 mutate(id = tolower(id)) %>% 
 left_join(df2 %>% mutate(id = tolower(id)), by = 'id')
```

which gives,

> ```
>       id   v1 v2 v3 M4 N4
> 1   xxx,   12 11 13 NA NA
> 2    mmm    w  n  m 10 23
> 3    ggg    Q  n  m NA NA
> 4 bccde,    w  P  m NA NA
> 5    qmc <NA>  T  p NA NA
> ```